# pycharm and subprocess - what works in console doesn't work in Pycharm

Tags: python, subprocess, pycharm

Pycharm's interpreter seems to have stopped understanding some of my console commands. It keeps recognizing default shell commands but doesn't recognize installed utilities.

For example, `subprocess` module understands `touch` command but doesn't understand `heroku` command.

The funny thing is, when I enter the same string into the console, with the same interpreter (from the same virtualenv), everything works fine.

A visual example:

[image]

It stopped working a couple days ago, and before that everything had worked fine.

I thought I had messed up some of my env vars, but opened an old project I hadn't touched for a month, and saw that the same `subprocess` commands stopped working there too.

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

Ok, I got this thing to work.

The values of `os.environ['PATH']` were different in console and in Pycharm. After I added the correct PATH to the Pycharm configuration env vars, everything started working again.

Now the question is, how do I avoid going through each configuration in each and every of my projects and adding this new PATH everywhere? Is there a way to do this globally and repair this one only setting that's been broken?

Comment: Hm, interesting :D Something like this happens to me only when I use pycharm on Windows and then I try to run it in linux environment, because of different line end characters (

Comment: \r\n vs \n) or because of the way how I form the path... try adding leading slash to your 'apps' (if it is a directory - I am not sure about Mac). Also, have you been updating your Project Interpreter in Pycharm lately?

Comment: they may work in different environment - with different 'PATH'. It seems PyCharm works in `virtualenv` but console don't have to.

Answer (score 3):

I see you figured out how to configure PyCharm's project PATH.

As for how to not have to do this for every project new project you start, you just have to update your default project configuration.

From [Accessing Default Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/accessing-default-settings.html):

> PyCharm helps define **settings** of a default project. These settings
>   are used as defaults every time you create a new project.
>
> **To access default project settings**
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose **File | Default Settings**
> 2. Define the desired settings in the [Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/settings-preferences-dialog.html) dialog box that opens.

**Note**: updates to the default project configurations only apply to future new projects, any existing project configuration needs to be updated manually.