# Module works in cmd but not in Pycharm

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, subprocess

I am trying to get PostGIS `shp2pgsql` and `pgsql2shp` modules to work in PyCharm. I can get them to work in the command prompt with no problems but not in a run of my script in PyCharm:

> 'shp2pgsql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Most similar google search found is [pycharm and subprocess - what works in console doesn't work in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724079/pycharm-and-subprocess-what-works-in-console-doesnt-work-in-pycharm), but it is not exactly the same.

I have set the path variable within PyCharm according to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/absolute-path-variables.html, but the same error is reproduced.

Here is my code:

```py
import time
import subprocess

command = 'shp2pgsql -I -d -s 27001 //d10/t/ca/analysis/road/extents/ne_extent.shp d.extent_ne| psql -q -d projects -h postgres.local'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
while process.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I'm using PyCharm version 2019.3.1 in Windows 10.

Comment: Are you using the correct Python Interpreter in PyCharm? I mean the same used in the cmd

Comment: I would assume that it is the same. I only have one installed. But I also don't think that the command prompt uses python at all in the call of shp2pgsql and pgsql2shp, so would that even matter?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings --> Tools --> Terminal --> project Settings and add in a new Environment Variable specifying the bin folder location of postgis. I also changed the start directory to C:\ instead of the path to the PyCharm project that I am currently working on. Not entirely sure which did the job, but it works now.