# Subprocess file not found on Pycharm but command works on console

Tags: python, pycharm, subprocess

My problem is that when I run (for example) `ifconfig` on my terminal I got regular output as expected. However, when I use the `subprocess` module on Pycharm to call a command it does not work raising `file not found` error.
I tried to use `which ifconfig` on my terminal obtaining the path of ifconfig succesfully: `/usr/sbin/ifconfig`.
So when I use the full path on the `subprocess` module the command works just fine, but I want to avoid this behaviour from pycharm just using the name of the command. I already seen this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724079/pycharm-and-subprocess-what-works-in-console-doesnt-work-in-pycharm)
but I didn't understand what the user did to setup a default value for `os.environ['PATH']`.